# Android: can't apply onclick listener to button inside custom arrayadapter<String>

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to dynamically add click listeners to a custom array adapter for a list view. The idea is that I have list objects with text on them (eg "Group 1", "Group 2" etc.), and then when I click on the object a drop down appears ("expandable_section") with two buttons on it ("Members" and "Settings"). When I click on the members button I want to be able to access the specific text on the original group object. For example, clicking "Members" under the "Group 1" tab would give me access to the text "Group 1."

Here is my XML layout for the custom adapter object:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- The list element for GROUP SETTINGS tab sub-section -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/activeIcon"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-7dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/modeIcon"
            android:layout_width="34dp"
            android:layout_height="34dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/groupName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
    </LinearLayout>


     <!-- SPECIAL HIDDEN TOOLBAR FOR DEMO LIBRARY LIST MODES TODO: Change to whitelist/blacklist GROUP TAB! -->
    <!-- EXPANDABLEFOR GROUP-SETTINGS FRAGMENT -->

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/expandableSubsection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/groupMembersButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Members" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/groupSettingsButton"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Settings" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the custom adapter code:

```
package com.sapphire.view;

import java.util.List;

import com.sapphire.model.Mode;
import com.sapphire.view.ModeAdapter.ModeHolder;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GroupAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
private Context context;
private int resource;

public GroupAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi =(LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(this.resource, null);
    }

            Button but= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

            if( but!=null){
                but.setId(position);
                but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        System.out.println("customgroup clicked !");
                    }                           
                  });

            }
    return v;

}
}
```

and here is where the custom adapter is actually used to display the list of groups:

```
    public void displayGroupsOptions(){
    final ListView lView = (ListView) thisView.findViewById(R.id.GroupsView);
final ArrayList<String> groupNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
lView.setAdapter(null); //empty the list view
//Get all groups from database table
System.out.println("customgroup about to get all groups from database");
    List<Group> allGroups = db.getAllGroups();
    if(!allGroups.isEmpty()){
        for (Group g: allGroups){
            groupNameList.add(g.getName());  
        }
        //Convert group arraylist to group array for use in adapter for list view
        String[] groupNameArray = (String[]) groupNameList.toArray(new String[0]);  

        GroupAdapter adapter = new GroupAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.group_list_row, R.id.groupName, groupNameList);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Creating an item click listener, to open/close the mode options toolbar for each item
        lView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                View groupOptions = view.findViewById(R.id.expandableSubsection);
                // Creating the expand animation for the item
                ExpandAnimation ea = new ExpandAnimation(groupOptions, ANIMATION_DELAY);
                // Start the animation on the toolbar
                groupOptions.startAnimation(ea);

            }
        });

    }
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated! I just can't figure out for the life of me how to get the proper text to show up on the tab (right now it's blank) and how to make the onclick listener actually attach and work. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a remark, you should use `groupNameList.toArray(new String[groupNameList.size()])` instead of `groupNameList.toArray(new String[0])` to avoid extra object creation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set tag for your Button in getView method to pass the position argument, and get the tag in th ClickListener.

```
btn.setTag(position);

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
}
```

Even you can set other view in the same adapter item as a tag and pass it to the listener.

Answer (score 0):

use this piece of code where you used getView in adapter class

```
public class ViewHolder {
    Button b;
    }
```

and also this

```
    @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;
if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz,
                parent, false);

holder.b = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else{
holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
Item it = item.get(position);
holder.b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


                    System.out.println("customgroup clicked !");
                }                           
              });


return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks I'll try this --what is mInflater from and item? And which layout should be referenced where you wrote R.layout.xyz?

Comment: So it seems like holder.b is not actually being set to a button. But I can't access the layout item for the button I want in R.id so it doesn't seem to be recognizing the layout in the first place...